# Why does PHP require double quotes for key variable in adding array key-value pairs?

Tags: php

Why does PHP require double quotes for key variable in adding array key-value pairs?

```
foreach($coreXml->Environment as $Environment) {
    $env = $Environment->Name;
    $envArr["$env"] ="test";
}
```

In this loop, if I don't use double quotes around the $env or use single quotes, it will break the code with error "Illegal offset type". Any idea on why that is? thanks!

Comment: No quotes should function the same as "$env" unless $env is null

Comment: and why the hell you need quotes in your case at all?

Comment: @MarkS That is the essence of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs everyone. Based on the answers below, it seems the problem occurred between the $env is a string not a number.

Comment: Take advice from @deceze: _" the problem is that you're trying to use a non-string as array offset, so an error message would be perfectly justified and preferable."_

Comment: It's a SimpleXML thing, you have to cast values to string or else you get an object. Nice catch by deceze.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do *not* require double quotes. `$envArr[$env]` is perfectly legal syntax.
`$envArr['$env']` would create the literal key `'$env'`, which is not what you want.

However, if `$env` is *not a string or integer*, but, say, an object or `null`, that's when you'd get an illegal offset notice. Interpolating the variable into a string with `"$env"` forces the variable to be cast to a string, which avoids that problem. But then arguably the problem is that you're trying to use a non-string as array offset, so an error message would be perfectly justified and preferable.

I'd be guessing that you're using SimpleXML and `$env` is a `SimpleXMLElement` object. You should be using this then:

```
$envArr[(string)$env]
// or
$envArr[$env->__toString()]
```

That's basically the same as encasing the variable in double quotes, it forces a string cast, but in this case it's explicit and not a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing $env is null or an object.  If null the case `$envArr[""]` would be the result of `$envArr["$env"]`  It's perfectly fine to have an empty string index.

Answer (score 1):

Check the manual for [string interpolation rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).  When you put variables inside of double quotes, their values will be interpolated.  When you put variables inside of single quotes, they will not be interpolated.  The following is literally trying to load the array at index `'$env`':

```
$envArray['$env']
```

Comment: It sure would if he's throwing an object inside those double quotes.

Comment: The code in your example would not cause an error, and it's not the code in the question.

Comment: The question: Why does PHP require double quotes for key variable in adding array key-value pairs? Answer: It doesn't, which follows from my explanation.

Comment: Yeah nevermind me, I see the issue now. He needed to cast to string.